# Dump string array using Windbg debugger commands

Tags: windbg

I'd like to dump a managed string array into a file where each line in the file corresponds to a single string in the array.

I have the the array address, so I've started with:

```
.foreach (ptr { !da <address> } ) {

}
```

How can I `.printf` the string given that the `!da` output looks like this:

```
[0] 000002104816bf00
[1] 000002104816c220
[2] 000002104816c528
```

Comment: `!do 000002104816bf00`?

Comment: @LexLi there are 10K strings in the array, I'm looking for a practical way to write them to a text file, Windbg debugger commands looked promising

Comment: If your goal is to write some automatic tooling, then ClrMD might be a better option than WinDbg, https://github.com/Microsoft/clrmd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, sure, it's possible - if you like the syntax of WinDbg...

Given a simple program like

```
using System;

namespace DumpStringArray
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            string[] a = new string[1000];
            for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
            {
                a[i] = "Line "+i;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Debug now");
            Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine(a[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

We first get the value of the local variable `a` using `!clrstack`:

```
0:000> !clrstack -a
[...]
0137ecf8 019e0516 *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for DumpStringArray.exe
DumpStringArray.Program.Main() [...\DumpStringArray\DumpStringArray\Program.cs @ 16]
    LOCALS:
        0x0137ed14 = 0x033c241c
        0x0137ed20 = 0x000003e8
        0x0137ed1c = 0x00000000

0137ee98 5cdaebe6 [GCFrame: 0137ee98] 

0:000> !DumpObj /d 033c241c
Name:        System.String[]
MethodTable: 5beb08b8
EEClass:     5ba84fc0
Size:        4012(0xfac) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 1000, Type CLASS (Print Array)
Fields:
None
0:000>
```

If you print that array, you'll see that it has a bunch of text before the actual list of items:

```
0:000> !DumpArray /d 033c241c
Name:        System.String[]
MethodTable: 5beb08b8
EEClass:     5ba84fc0
Size:        4012(0xfac) bytes
Array:       Rank 1, Number of elements 1000, Type CLASS
Element Methodtable: 5beafd60
[0] 033c4a98
[1] 033c4ad0
[2] 033c4b08
[...]
```

Let's count the number of tokens before the list starts:

1. `Name:`
2. `System.String[]`
3. `MethodTable:`
4. `5beb08b8`
5. `EEClass:`
6. `5ba84fc0`
7. `Size:`
8. `4012(0xfac)`
9. `bytes`
10. `Array:`
11. `Rank`
12. `1,`
13. `Number`
14. `of`
15. `elements`
16. `1000,`
17. `Type`
18. `CLASS`
19. `Element`
20. `Methodtable:`
21. `5beafd60`
22. `[0]`

Therefore, you need `/pS 0n22` in the `.foreach`loop in order to skip those.

Next, you need `/ps 0n1` to skip all other array indexes.

The command thus far would be `.foreach /pS 0n22 /ps 0n1 (str {!da <address>}) { }`.

Now, a .NET string has a header, so the actual string content does not start at the address, but somewhat later:

```
0:000> !do 033d42a4
Name:        System.String
MethodTable: 5beafd60
EEClass:     5ba84e90
Size:        30(0x1e) bytes
File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_32\mscorlib\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\mscorlib.dll
String:      Line 999
Fields:
      MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
5beb1bc0  400027b        4         System.Int32  1 instance        8 m_stringLength
5beb07a8  400027c        8          System.Char  1 instance       4c m_firstChar
5beafd60  4000280       60        System.String  0   shared   static Empty
    >> Domain:Value  01408b18:NotInit  <<
```

As you can see, the offset of the first character is `8`.

We can use `du` to display Unicode strings at a given offset, so the command is now:

```
.foreach /pS 0n22 /ps 0n1 (str {!da <address>}) { du ${str}+8 }
```

Unfortunately, this will output the address and the text:

```
0:000> .foreach /pS 0n22 /ps 1 (str {!da 033c241c}){du ${str}+8}
033c4aa0  "Line 0"
033c4ad8  "Line 1"
033c4b10  "Line 2"
[...]
```

So yes, you need `.printf` to fix that:

```
.foreach /pS 0n22 /ps 1 (str {!da 033c241c}){.printf "%mu\n", (${str}+8)}
```

Now, this works on 32 bit. I leave the 64 bit migration as an exercise for you.

Use `.logopen` before to open a text file, and `.logclose` after that.

Comment: The detail and explanation of this response is incredibly helpful